# How to run multiple modules within a module in parallel?

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network

I've been reading a paper which contained the following machine learning model which I would like to replicate in PyTorch

[image]

Essentially the input gets split into n equally sized vectors and each of them gets passed to a separate local model. All outputs of local models are then concatenated and run through the next layer. (x is not relevant to my question here, so let's ignore it)

So far I've come up with this:

```
class GlobalModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_local_models):
        super(GlobalModel, self).__init__()

        self.local_models = [LocalModel() for _ in range(n_local_models)]
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(100, 100)  
        self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU()
```

with LocalModel being some other torch.nn.Module. The linear Layer size is just a dummy, I will make it change dynamically with the local models later.

My question is, how can I best write a forward() function that runs all local models in parallel, before concatenating them and passing them on to the linear layer and activation function. Because the only way of implementing this that I can think of, is iterating through the list of local models and executing each of them in sequence. But this seems rather slow and I feel like there should be a more elegant solution.

Comment: have a link to the paper?

Comment: My personal take would be the loop would not be matter much compared to the parallel execution, provided that you can utilize all GPUs (and their capacity). From my experience, running 8 commands, each on 1GPU does not differ much from running 8 commands sequentially, each on 8 GPUs. BUT, the second one is much easier to implement and organize.

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple modules in parallel, you often want multiple processes (and multiple GPUs). Python isn't very good at multithreading (due to the GIL).

Even without Python, GPU programming is highly optimized for parallelizing large individual operations performed over a tensor, not for performing multiple separate operations in parallel. To perform separate operations in parallel on a single GPU, you'd need to send them to different GPU executors ("streams").

You didn't link to the paper, but it's also sometimes the case that splitting an operation into multiple parallel modules is done just to better utilize multiple GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Some clarifying questions.

How many GPUs do you have access to?

Are the local models pre-trained or trained in-line? If they are pre-trained, is it necessary to backprop through them?

GPUs really do not like parallel processing within a single card. If you have access to multiple cards, you can look into parallelizing the local models across multiple cards. If you don't have enough GPUs for this, you're better off running the local models in series. Multi-model parallel processing with card sharing will be a huge pain and most likely be slower than running in series.

If the local models are pre-trained and you don't need to backprop through them, you can consider building a feature extraction pipeline that computes local model outputs prior to training.